# Save ongoing measurement into csv file

Tags: python, csv, export

I would like to store data into csv file. But the data are incrementing with time. I wrote a simple example to show the problem :

```
import csv
import time
i = 0
with open('testfile.csv','wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=';',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    while True:
        i = i+1
        print i
        writer.writerow([i])    
        time.sleep(2)
```

When the while loop is running the csv file is not written. But when I stop the program then the data are stored in the csv file.
Is there a possibility to keep the program running and 'force' the writing into the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writing in python is buffered. you can force to write the output (flush the buffer) with:

```
csvfile.flush()
```

in your code i suggest you add this line right after `writer.writerow([i])`.

you could also pass a `buffering` argument to the [`open() function`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) - but i suggest you do not do that; switching buffering off comes with a performance penalty.